# Descending Sorting Algorithm

Tags: java, sorting

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RandExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            int MethodChoice = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What method would you like to use to sort the random numbers" + "\n" + "1 - Selection Sort" + "\n" + "2 - Bubble Sort" + "\n" + "3 - Insertion Sort" + "\n" + "4 - Quick Sort"));

            if (MethodChoice == 1) {

                    int iTotalCount = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the total number of integers?"));

                    int SortOrder = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("1 - Ascending  "
                            + "2 - Descending"));

                    if (SortOrder == 2) {
                         int[] array = new int[iTotalCount];

                        System.out.println("After sorting using the Selection Sort, " + "Using Descending Order" + "the array is: ");

                        for(int count = array.length-1; count >= 0; count--)
                             System.out.print(array[count] + " ");

                        selectionSortReverse(array);

                    }

                    int[] array = new int[iTotalCount];

                    Random randomGenerator = new Random();

                    for (int i = 0; i < iTotalCount; i++) {
                       array[i] = randomGenerator.nextInt(1001);
                       System.out.print(" " + array[i]);
                    }

                    System.out.println("\n---------------------------------");
                    selectionSort(array);

                    //print out sorted list
                    System.out.println("After sorting using the Selection Sort," + " the array is:");
                    for (int count = 0; count < array.length; count++) {
                         System.out.print(array[count] + " ");
                    }
    }
```

I have a subroutine that calls selectionSortReverse(array); when the users picks 2 to have it sort in descending, but when I hit 2, and proceed, it posts the numbers in ascending. Do I have it placed somewhere wrong? Here's my selectionSortReverse subroutine:

```
 public static void selectionSortReverse(int data[]) {
     int smallest;
     for (int i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
         smallest = i;
         //see if there is a smaller number further in the array
         for (int index = i + 1; index < data.length; index++) {
              if (data[index] > data[smallest]) {
                  swap(data, smallest, index);
              }
         }
     }
 }
```

**UPDATED CODE USING cricket_007'S SUGGESTION**

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;
public class RandExample {

private static int[] generateRandomArray(int size, int randomMax) {
    int[] array = new int[size];
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        array[i] = randomGenerator.nextInt(randomMax);
    }
    return array;
}


    public static void main(String[] args) {




            int MethodChoice = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What method would you like to use to sort the random numbers" + "\n" + "1 - Selection Sort" + "\n" + "2 - Bubble Sort" + "\n" + "3 - Insertion Sort" + "\n" + "4 - Quick Sort"));

            if (MethodChoice == 1) {

                    int iTotalCount = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the total number of integers?"));

                    int SortOrder = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("1 - Ascending  "
                            + "2 - Descending"));


                    if (SortOrder == 2) {
                        int[] array = generateRandomArray(iTotalCount, 1001);
                        selectionSortReverse(array);

                        for(int count = array.length-1; count >= 0; count--)
                            System.out.print(array[count] + " ");
                        System.out.println("\n---------------------------------");

                        System.out.println("After sorting using the Selection Sort, " + "Using Descending Order" + " " + "the array is: ");

                        for(int i : array) {
                            System.out.print(i + " ");
                        }
                    } else if (SortOrder == 1) {
                        int[] array = generateRandomArray(iTotalCount, 1001);
                        selectionSort(array);

                        for(int count = array.length-1; count >= 0; count--)
                            System.out.print(array[count] + " ");
                        System.out.println("\n---------------------------------");


                        System.out.println("After sorting using the Selection Sort," + " the array is:");

                        for(int i : array) {
                            System.out.print(i + " ");
                        }
                    }
```

**UPDATE 3**

Code works from Selection ---> Bubble, insertion not so much. The printing of random integers is in the same format as the sorted list.

Here's the code:

```
 } else if (MethodChoice == 3) {
         if (SortOrder == 2) {
               insertionSortReverse(array);
                System.out.println("After sorting using the Insertion Sort, " + "Using Descending Order" + " " + "the array is: ");
            } else if (SortOrder == 1) {
                insertionSort(array);


                System.out.println("After sorting using the Insertion Sort," + " the array is:");

    }

    for (int i : array) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
     }
    }
```

Here are my insertionSort() and insertionSortReverse() subs:

```
public static void insertionSort(int data[]) {
    int insert;

    for (int next = 1; next < data.length; next++) {
      insert = data[next];
      int moveItem = next;

      while (moveItem > 0 && data[moveItem - 1] > insert) {
        data[moveItem] = data[moveItem - 1];
        moveItem--;
      }
      data[moveItem] = insert;
    }
  }

public static void insertionSortReverse(int data[]) {
    int insert;

    for (int next = 1; next < data.length; next++) {
      insert = data[next];
      int moveItem = next;

      while (moveItem < 0 && data[moveItem - 1] < insert) {
        data[moveItem] = data[moveItem - 1];
        moveItem--;
      }
      data[moveItem] = insert;
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is why rather than doing your own compare function, you should be using a Comparator. If you were, you could just use reverseOrder(): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#reverseOrder--

Comment: @ControlAltDel - That is assuming this is Java8

Comment: I just found that calling the new subroutine seemed to be a lot more easier. I had the feeling that maybe it had something to do with the if-statement for when they select the order they want. Maybe it just keeps going back to the regular code instead of the one I put in the if code block? @ControlAltDel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either your problem is when you hit 2 and proceed and it posts the numbers in ascending order is because you don't have an else statement around your ascending code, or you are sorting the array in reverse, then printing the list backwards. Also, your posted descending code was sorting a list of zeros anyways...

```
private static int[] generateRandomArray(int size, int randomMax) {
    int[] array = new int[size];
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        array[i] = randomGenerator.nextInt(randomMax);
    }
    return array;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int MethodChoice = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What method would you like to use to sort the random numbers" + "\n" + "1 - Selection Sort" + "\n" + "2 - Bubble Sort" + "\n" + "3 - Insertion Sort" + "\n" + "4 - Quick Sort"));
    int iTotalCount = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the total number of integers?"));
    int SortOrder = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("1 - Ascending, " + "2 - Descending"));

    int[] array = generateRandomArray(iTotalCount, 1001);

    System.out.println("Randomly Generated number list: ");
    for (int i : array) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("\n---------------------------------");

    if (MethodChoice == 1) {
        if (SortOrder == 2) {
            selectionSortReverse(array);
            System.out.println("After sorting using the Selection Sort, " + "Using Descending Order" + "the array is: ");
        } else if (SortOrder == 1) {
            selectionSort(array);
            System.out.println("After sorting using the Selection Sort," + " the array is:");
        }
    } else if (MethodChoice == 2) {
        // bubble-sort
    }

    for (int i : array) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: When i try implementing this into my code it underlines array and tells me it's a duplicate, and when I remove the duplicates whole bunch of errors come up. Is it possible to do it as is with my code instead of having to switch the loops?

Comment: You can only have one declaration of `int[] array` in the same scope. The following assignments just need to be `array`. And the foreach loop that I used can be replaced with the for loop you used. There just was no need for use of your `count` variable. @Jcrow

Comment: where do I happen to put the first part of the code you posted? In the SortOrder{} or in the MethodChoice{} block?

Comment: It is a separate method outside of `main` in the `RandExample` class. @Jcrow

Comment: The second block is the entire contents of your `if (MethodChoice == 1) { }` block. @Jcrow

Comment: Thank you! Your code works just fine. I assume now I basically just apply this concept to the rest of the code?

Comment: Yep! And I updated my answer for completion. Since you are probably going to prompt for the values in each "MethodChoice" anyways, you should just get all your values ahead of time. @Jcrow

Comment: thanks again! And I found something interesting, when I generate the random numbers, it generates the random integers lowest to highest instead of just randomly

Comment: this is only though when I choose descending as an option, ascending has them randomly :) I posted your code implemented into mine in the OP @cricket_007

Comment: Ok. I just updated my answer again anyway. If you could accept my answer, then I would appreciate it. And I still don't understand why you are printing the array backwards. @Jcrow

Comment: It's "correct" in that it prints all the elements, but normally loops say `(int i = 0; i < size; i++)`, reading left-to-right. Along with that thought, though. You could literally just right one sort method for either order, then print the list in reverse for the other order... :) @Jcrow

Comment: I tried your code as well, erased mine and just pasted yours, and it doesn't print the numbers at all, it just says the string that I have it to output to console, no numbers at all. @cricket_007

Comment: Try copying the whole thing :) The numbers print at the very end this time instead of inside the if-else. @Jcrow

Comment: @crow_007 now it prints the sorted order, but I want to have it print the numbers before it gets sorted so if i run it lets say, it does:


Randomly Generated number list: 45 201 920 102
------------------------

Sorted in descending: 920 201 102 45

The second parts good, the first part is what I'm stuck on, I change the loop, and it messes the whole program up!

Comment: If you want to print the list before sorting it, then do that. Updated answer again. @Jcrow

Comment: thank you so much, it works up to the first 2 sorting methods, then for the 3rd it stops, one of the curly braces is underlined, but Eclipse won't give me a proper error. I updated the OP with the code to hopefully help. I believe the formatting is fine, so I'm not quite sure what it is, because I followed the layout of the first 2, but still managed to mess up!

Comment: One of your curly braces doesn't match and Eclipse won't tell you where because the code can't compile. From what you pasted, you are missing one above `for (int i : array)`. I suggest you format your code to match indenting and make a new question for further assistance because I've already answered your initial problem and there is no reason to keep updating the same post with additional problems. @Jcrow

Comment: I understand thank you for the help! And I fixed the issue as far as the curly braces go, just had to readjust where it went and add some additional code to balance it out. Thank you so much for everything, you're awesome!